# How to return a format string and why my button don't show up?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want the value show like this [This is what I want when I select 10 in listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJtiE.png), but It show like this when I trying [Now what its look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei4VR.png)  I can't find a way to set it format by using f-string, also I added a button that call "Test Yourselves", After I press it will make the listbox (visible = False) but I don't know why I can make the button (visible = True) can any anybody can tell me where I code it wrong?

```
from tkinter.constants import CHAR
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import Exit


def corecode(base):
    if base == 1:
        show1 = f'{1:>3d} * {1:>3d} = {1:> 3d}\n {2:>3d} * {1:>3d} = {2:> 3d}\n {3:>3d} * {1:>3d} = {3:> 3d}\n {4:>3d} * {1:>3d} = {4:> 3d}\n'
        return show1
    else:
        return ("\n"+"-"*13+"\n").join([f'{i+1:>2d} * {j:>2d} = {(i+1)*base:>3d}' for i in range(10)])
def test():
    showquestion = "What is 9 X 9 ? \n 1. 81 \n 2. 12 \n 3. 22 \n 4. 68 "
    return showquestion
sg.theme('LightBLue')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

showrobot_column = [
    [sg.Image('E:/img/Gif_robot.gif', size = (700, 700))],
    [sg.Exit()]
]
showtest_column =[
    [sg.Button('1', enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-Button-")],
    [sg.Button('2', enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-Button-")],
    [sg.Button('3', enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-Button-")],
    [sg.Button('4', enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-Button-")],
]
list_values = [f'{i+1:>2d}' for i in range(10)]
show_Textbox_selectbox = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(15, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=list_values, enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-"),sg.Button('Test Yourselves',key="-Test-")],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(showrobot_column),
     sg.VSeparator(),
     sg.Column(showtest_column,visible = False),
     sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox),],
]

window = sg.Window("First Test", layout, finalize=True)
multiline = window['-MULTILINE-']
multiline.update(value=corecode(1))
listbox = window['-LISTBOX-']
listbox.update(set_to_index=0)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        base = int(values[event][0])
        multiline.update(value=corecode(base))
    elif event == '-Test-':
        multiline.update(value =test())
        window['-LISTBOX-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-Button-'].Update(visible = True)
        window['-Test-'].Update(visible = False)

window.close()
```

About the visible problem picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0jA.png)
I want to make it like this picture there should be 4 button which using to select 1,2,3,4 answer the question, but I don't know why it didn't show up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues

- `from PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI import Exit` is wrong or not required, and it is ok to use `sg.Exit()` or `sg.Button('Exit')`.
- Width of a line is too long to fit width of multiline, so it wrap to next line.
- Option `enable_events` is not necessary for `sg.Button` for most of cases.
- Every element (Button) must have a unique key. Button '1', '2', '3' and '4' with same option `key='-Button-'` is wrong.
- Set option `visible=False` will get element missed its location, so `sg.pin` used to keep the location.
- With option `expand_y=True` to fill available space in vertical direction, remember to expand its container if necessary, or no more space to expand.
- Option `expand_x` and `expand_y` will missed after element set to invisible, so need to call method `expand` to recover it when element set to visible.
- Maybe something else.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def corecode(base):
    j = 4 if base == 1 else 10
    return ("\n"+"-"*13+"\n").join([f'{i+1:>2d} * {base:>2d} = {(i+1)*base:>3d}' for i in range(j)])

def test():
    question = ["What is 9 X 9 ?", " 1. 81", " 2. 12", " 3. 22", " 4. 68"]
    return '\n'.join(question)

sg.theme('LightBLue')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

showrobot_column = [
    [sg.Image('E:/img/Gif_robot.gif', size = (700, 700))],
    [sg.Exit()]
]
showtest_column =[[sg.Button(str(i+1), size=(15, 1), expand_y=True)] for i in range(4)]

list_values = [f'{i+1:>2d}' for i in range(10)]
show_Textbox_selectbox = [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(20, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Listbox(values=list_values, enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-")),
     sg.pin(sg.Button('Test Yourselves', key="-Test-"))],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(showrobot_column, expand_y=True),
     sg.VSeparator(),
     sg.pin(sg.Column(showtest_column, visible=False, expand_y=True,key='-Buttons-'), expand_y=True),
     sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox, expand_y=True),],
]

window = sg.Window("First Test", layout, finalize=True)
multiline = window['-MULTILINE-']
multiline.update(value=corecode(1))
listbox = window['-LISTBOX-']
listbox.update(set_to_index=0)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, event == 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        base = int(values[event][0])
        multiline.update(value=corecode(base))
    elif event == '-Test-':
        multiline.update(value=test())
        window['-LISTBOX-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-Buttons-'].Update(visible = True)
        window['-Buttons-'].expand(expand_y=True)
        window['-Test-'].Update(visible = False)
    elif event in (str(i+1) for i in range(4)):
        print(f"Selection is {event}")

window.close()
```